# How do I use the onmousemove event?

Tags: javascript, onmousemove

How can I make it so that the following code will be executed only when the move moves using the `onmousemove` event.

`settimeout(function(){ confirm("Hello"); }, 3000);`

I'm looking for a pure JavaScript solution only.

Comment: `settimeout` wont work - it has to be `setTimeout` (JavaScript is case-sensitive).

Answer (score 0):

You could handle the `mousemove` event by doing something similar to what I have below:

```js
var handler = function(e) {
  console.clear();
  console.log(`Mouse at: X:${e.screenX} Y:${e.screenY}`);
}

document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  //setTimeout(function() {
  handler(e);
  //}, 1000)
});
```

```html
<body>
  <p>Here is some text
  </p>
  <p>Event should fire when hovering
  </p>
  <p>any text in a child element of document.body
  </p>
</body>
```

In my example I commented out the `setTimeout` (which is case-sensitive, by the way) method and just log the X and Y coordinates of the mouse pointer at the time of the event. You could put whatever you want in the handler - I just didn't think that worked well for the sake of an event handling example.